# List Box - first item remains selected

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I created a list box in an ms-access VBA-form with the following properties:

```
OverlapFlags =85
IMESentenceMode =3
Left =56
Top =282
Width =8160
Height =963
TabIndex =5
Name ="xOnlineTypen"
ControlSource ="[OAT_NAME]"
RowSourceType ="Table/Query"
RowSource ="SELECT [OAT_NAME], [LFD] from [TABLE]"
OnDblClick ="[Event Procedure]"
ControlTipText ="Die unterstützten Onlineantragstypen"
GUID = Begin
    0x463f...bb06f69
End

LayoutCachedLeft =56
LayoutCachedTop =282
LayoutCachedWidth =8216
LayoutCachedHeight =1245
Begin
    Begin Label
        OverlapFlags =85
        Left =60
        Width =2295
        Height =240
        Name ="Bezeichnungsfeld159"
        Caption ="Unterstütze Antragstypen:"
        GUID = Begin
            0x7f1ed40...c4f9c7ee
        End
        LayoutCachedLeft =60
        LayoutCachedWidth =2355
        LayoutCachedHeight =240
    End
End
```

The problem is, when I display the form, the first item remained selected even when I try to change it. When I use the mouse to click on the second item in the list there is a beep and nothing else happens.

I already tried to delete the list box and create it new (in case the list box was corrupted) but it did not work out. I also tried to change some properties (multiselect, ControlSource, RowSource, BoundColumn, ...) but it changes nothing.

Why is that?

What

Comment: Why are you using code to establish a listbox? What event is code in? Tagged as VBA but does not look like VBA. You have a table named TABLE?

Comment: The list box was created with the designer (as usual). This "code" is a part of the file which is created when you export the form with the function "SaveAsText". I did this because I dont wanted to type all the properties by hand. And the table [TABLE] is not called [TABLE]. I just dont wanted to tell the internet how the tables in my company are named.

Comment: I have never exported forms. Why don't you post relevant code? I certainly don't see anything wrong with properties. Why would using actual table names be an issue?

Comment: "Why don't you post relevant code?" Because I did not write any code. Everything was created with the designer.

Comment: The properties list shows OnDblClick event has been set to `[Event Procedure]`, that means VBA code. So if you did not write any code into procedure, then nothing should be preventing listbox to work. Sorry, there is no code to analyze and I can't interact with your listbox so can't advise solution.

Comment: The OnDblClick -event handler is empty (exept of a 'TODO:-comment for later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It was the property: ControlSource

As far as I understand this: If the property ControlSource is filled out the list box tries to write the current selection to the database. As the list box was only for reading, this was not possible so the system locked the selection.

So I had to empty the property ControlSource and everything was fine.